# Why isn't Android dependency relative path working?

Tags: android, gradle, jar, dependencies, relative-path

Directory structure:

```
/root/app/libs
/root/app/build.gradle
/root/common-libs/foo.jar
                  bar.jar
```

To include all the jars under /root/common-libs

```
   compile fileTree(dir: '../common-libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

Not working. Importing classes from the common libs can not be resolved.

If I copy all the jars under the common-libs to the /root/app/libs, it will work.
Can the relative path like the example above be used?

Comment: add your stack trace .. what are the errors?

Comment: well. the classes from the common-libs can not be imported. It is compiling error.